# Can DBT generate SQL statements which can be used for multiple sources?

Tags: dbt

I have multiple date sources say(Sonwflake, SQL, redshift...), As of now I was generating SQL statements using a factory pattern. For examples to apply limit in various databases like,

Snowflake: `select * from table_name limit 10 offset 0`,

MySQL:     `select * from table_name limit 10, 0`

Using DBT:

- Can it be possible to generate SQL statements based on config, macros(or any) per source?
- Can a project and generate for multiple data sources connectors?

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Dbt creates an insert/merge query statement comprised of a CTE statement used as a ref to connect one model file to another.

Hence, if a database supports your final query syntax it will be able to create the SQL that you require by changing the target database config, but in case it's not supported then it will give a syntax error.

Dbt is not an extractor it's used for transformation, hence it needs data in the warehouse. You can read more about it: [connecting-to-two-dbs-not-allowed](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/faqs/connecting-to-two-dbs-not-allowed)